# list of objects to listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Suppose I have a class name Employee. I have another class called Controller, which is a list of Employee objects. The point is that I cannot figure out how to make that list display in a listview.

Assume the following code (for the sake of simplicity, I will reduce the code to a bare minimum):

```
    class Employee
    {
            string name;
            string position;

            public Employee(string inputName, string inputPosition)
            {
                this.name = inputName;
                this.position = inputPosition;
            }
        public string getName()         { return name;          }
        public string getPosition()     { return position;      }
    }
```

Now the Controller class:

```
class Controller
{
        List<Employee> employeeList;

        public Controller()
        {
            employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        }

        public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() { return employeeList; }
}
```

Now, I want to display the NAMES in a listbox. So far I have:

```
Controller ctrl = new Controller();
ctrl.addEmployee("testname1", "testjob1");
ctrl.addEmployee("testname2", "testjob2");

listBox1.DataSource = ctrl.getEmployeeList();
```

This makes the listbox print out the current namespace of the list. Searching google led me to believe that I need to use listbox1.DisplayMember, but

```
listbox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

does not help. It probably defaults to .ToString() because it doesn't find the 'name' property in the controller class. How could I handle this? I think I'm missing something obvious, I've been stalling on this for almost 2 hours, I'm not so experienced with .net.

Comment: dont you need to DataBind() like we do for GridView?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: This is WinForms. There is no need to call DataBind explicitly as in ASP.NET, I assume.

Comment: well I did have an assignment with DataGridView and it worked fine without the DataBind(). I generally avoid DataBind(). do you think I should try using it? although I don't see a reason I would.

Comment: @icarus: No, need. You need figure out the difference between fields and properties in C#.

Comment: @PaulSasik that's exactly the point I was missing! I'm looking into properties and fields now. thanks a bunch!

Comment: @icarus: No problem. I was similarly tripped up when I started in WinForms.  Unfortunattely there was no such thing as SO at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DisplayMember` has to be a **public Property** and not a private field! (See [this MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for DisplayMember information and a full example.)

You have:

```
string name; // by default this is a private field of the Employee class
```

You need:

```
public string Name { get { return name;} }
```

and:

```
listbox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried making the name property private. still not working :-s.

Comment: @icarus: Please read my answer more closely. `name` is a private field and not a public property. Create a public property like this: `public string Name { get { return name;} }` and remember that C# is case sensitive so name != Name.

Comment: oh! I understand now. I'm sorry, I read it completely wrong. Thanks a lot, this solved my problem!